# Unable to display actual chart using Google API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, linechart, google-visualization

I am displaying a chart using Google API and I am getting a chart but it is not displaying that line in the graph,

This is the code I am trying with, I am using array data for charts,

```
 var jsonlength = data.feed.entry.length;
 var timestamp = new Array(jsonlength);
 var temperature = new Array(jsonlength);
 var tempid = new Array(jsonlength);

 for (var i = 0; i < jsonlength; i++) {
    timestamp[i] = ((data.feed.entry[i].gsx$timestamp.$t)); 
    temperature[i] = ((data.feed.entry[i].gsx$temperaturevalue.$t)); 
}

google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data1.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data1.addColumn('number', 'X');


    for (var i = 0; i < jsonlength; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        data1.addRows(i,data.feed.entry[i].gsx$temperaturevalue.$t);
        //Here I can display all those values, But still not getting the chart, Though I have given proper values, Help me here 
        console.log(data.feed.entry[i].gsx$temperaturevalue.$t);
    }         
      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Date'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Temperature'
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data1, options);
```

This is the output I am getting without a line, Please help me I am new to this

[Output without a line in the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBFzp.png)

Answer (score 0):

most likely is due to `'string'` values vs. `number`

try this...

```
temperature[i] = (parseFloat(data.feed.entry[i].gsx$temperaturevalue.$t));
```

here...

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonlength; i++) {
  timestamp[i] = ((data.feed.entry[i].gsx$timestamp.$t)); 
  temperature[i] = (parseFloat(data.feed.entry[i].gsx$temperaturevalue.$t));
}
```

**EDIT**

here, you create `data`

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

but then you're adding columns to `data1` ???

```
  data1.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'X');
```

try syncing up the variable names and check `addRow` below...

```
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'X');


for (var i = 0; i < jsonlength; i++) {

    // use addRow -- which takes an array
    data1.addRow([i,data.feed.entry[i].gsx$temperaturevalue.$t]);

}         

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Date'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Temperature'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data1, options);
```

Comment: Sir I have modified my code, Please have a look at it